# Can you import a variable declared inside a function while using OOP in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, module

I am using ES6 classes and modules. I have a method in my `location` module that gets the user's latitude and longitude. I in turn want to import them to another module where I will interact with the openWeatherApi.

Here are my code samples

This my location module,that holds the location class

```
class Location {
  constructor() {
    this.getPosition();
  }

  getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoords, this.error);
  }

  getCoords(position) {
    const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
  }

  error(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}


export { Location };
```

here is my module where I will interact with the openweatherApi

```
import { Location } from "./location.js";

const userLocation = new Location();

console.log(userLocation.latitude);
console.log(userLocation.longitude);
```

Please how can I access the longitude and latitude variable declared in the location module, in my new module.

Comment: You can't. They won't be available immediately, you will have to wait for them. Use promises.

Comment: Also no reason to use a `class` here (and constructors shouldn't be abused to run side effects). Make a simple function that returns a promise for the location.

Comment: This has nothing to do with modules btw. It would (not) work in exactly the same way if the class/function and its usage were inside the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access by this way the longitude and latitude. Cause both are local varibles.

You have to define both variables as member variables.

```
constructor() {
    this.longitude = undefined;
    this.latitude = undefined;
    this.getPosition();
}

getCoords(position) {
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude ;
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
    console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is only a very very tiny part of the problem

Comment: @Bergi Oh, yeah yet i can see as well.

Comment: Well this actually answers the literal question : "how can you import a variable declared inside a function while using OOP in javascript?" - you do that by making the variable a property. Even though the code in the question has another problem which is that the data has to be loaded first.